# What should be the subject line to use in an email asking to join a research lab?

Tags: politeness, email

I'm interested in joining one of the research labs in my university and I would like to arrange a meeting with a professor or visit his lab office to discuss if I could join his lab. But I do not know if what I have been using sounds natural and if I have been using it wrongly.

What could be the possible subject lines of the email? Does the following sound natural? Or what could be other better subject lines?

- Question about joining your lab
- May I come to you office to discuss the possibility of joining your lab?

Comment: **sound *natural***.  The verb **sound** like **seem** and **look** wants an adjective to complement the subject, not an adverb.

Comment: The subject line of an email is typically not a fully-formed sentence but a fragment that identifies the subject matter. Since there is limited space on the display device, rules similar to those governing headlines in newspapers are in effect.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thanks, edited. Could you suggest some other better options in your opinion?

Comment: Any answer here is purely subjective. We can really only help with something specific.

Answer (score 1):

E-mail subject lines are generally short fragments.  I would avoid using a full sentence ("May I come to you office to discuss the possibility of joining your lab?") or placing the key point of the e-mail in the subject ("Question about joining your lab").

The actual subject line is up to you but I would consider something like:

> "Request for meeting"
>
> "Research opportunities"
>
> "Laboratory visit"

And then explain one's intentions in the body of the e-mail.